# button click handler not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to attach the ExportPDF to the button exportSelectedPdf on a cshtml file but when I click the button the handler is not working. Any ideas why ?

```
<input id="exportSelectedPdf" type="button" value="Export to PDF" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function ExportPDF() {
        alert("Hi");
        var url=@Url.Action("ExportTransactionsAsPdf", "JournalController");
        exportSelectedTransactions(url);
    }

    document.getElementById("exportSelectedPdf").addEventListener("click", ExportPDF());

</script>
```

Comment: first of all check console for any js errors

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis from your EventListener `("click", ExportPDF)`

Comment: Most likely the url isn't escaped. `var url='@Url.Action("ExportTransactionsAsPdf", "JournalController")';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replay. Still can not get the attached button to work. I defined the onclick handler inline and that worked for me.

```
 <input id="exportSelectedPdf" type="button" value="Export Selected Transactions to PDF" 
    onclick="var url='@Url.Action("ExportTransactionsAsPdf", "Journal", new {area="Journal"})';exportSelectedTransactions(url);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing client side with server side. Try this.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ExportTransactionsAsPdf", "JournalController")';
```

and bind event like this

```
document.getElementById("exportSelectedPdf").addEventListener("click", ExportPDF);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
<input id="exportSelectedPdf" type="button" value="Export to PDF" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ExportPDF() {
alert("Hi");
var url=@Url.Action("ExportTransactionsAsPdf", "JournalController")
;
exportSelectedTransactions(url);
}
document.getElementById("exportSelectedPdf").addEventListener("click", ExportPDF);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach a `function` reference as "click" listener, not the result of it.
Change:

```
document.getElementById("exportSelectedPdf").addEventListener("click", ExportPDF());
```

to the (not immediately call the function, just pass the reference to it):

```
document.getElementById("exportSelectedPdf").addEventListener("click", ExportPDF);
```